# Can't align TR tags in handling table with double template tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make table for handling variable two kinds of row DB with two template tags. But, 2nd DB is not align with 1st DB. 2nd DB rows is in the first column, not row. When I see the html layout in debug mode, there is no `<tr>` tag in 2nd DB. How to handle it?

```
<HTML Source>

<tbody id="result">
</tbody>

<template id="template1">
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class = "search">
 </tr>
</template>
<template id="template2">
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
</template>

<script>
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("result");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("template1");
var template = templateBox.content;
searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";  

 for(i=0;i<2;i++){

    tr = template.cloneNode(true);
 
    var detailInfoBox = tr.querySelector(".search");
    var templateInfoBox = document.getElementById("template2")
    var templateInfo = templateInfoBox.content;
     detailInfoBox.innerHTML = "";
    
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
     var tr1 = templateInfo.cloneNode(true); 
     
        detailInfoBox.appendChild(tr1)
         
    }
  
    searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
   
  
  }
</script>

codepan : https://codepen.io/greenfd/pen/QWvObQR
```

Comment: what is your expected result look like?

Comment: what I expect is that a, b, c <td> tags includs <tr> tag. please refer below link for expected result : https://codepen.io/greenfd/pen/BaRmjbJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never create a new `tr` and you append all cloned `td` into the same `tr`.

So you need to create a new `tr` and append after the existing `tr` by :

```
detailInfoBox.after($(`<tr></tr>`).html(tr1)[0])
```

```js
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("result");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("template1");
var template = templateBox.content;
searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    tr = template.cloneNode(true);

    var detailInfoBox = tr.querySelector(".search");
    var templateInfoBox = document.getElementById("template2")
    var templateInfo = templateInfoBox.content;
    detailInfoBox.innerHTML = "";

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var tr1 = templateInfo.cloneNode(true);
        detailInfoBox.after($(`<tr></tr>`).html(tr1)[0])
    }

    searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <table border="1">
        <tbody id="result">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <template id="template1">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="search">
        </tr>
    </template>
    <template id="template2">
        <td> a </td>
        <td> b </td>
        <td> c </td>
    </template>
```

Comment: @greenfield Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @ Alireza Ahmadi  Great. it was solved. Thanks a lot~~~